# Javascript/ jQuery and regex

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, regex, preg-match

I"m building a registration form, and I need to validate the user's inputs. (username, email, password).

I have regular expressions set up for each of these, and I can easily validate each in PHP using preg_match, and if it returns false, I can display an error.

However, I think it'd be much nicer if the page did not have to refresh to display the error. Is there a javascript/ jQuery equivalent of preg_match?

Thanks in advance for the help! I really appreciate it.

(PS, I've seen the jQuery "validate" plugin, but I'd much prefer to do it myself)

Answer (score 3):

Sure here is ref: [from w3cscools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Yes - [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) is native to JavaScript.  It will match a string against a regular expression.

(See [Regular expression field validation in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345194/regular-expression-matching-in-jquery#answer-345259) for an example of matching inside jQuery.)