# How do i check if a substring matches with regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to find out if my string contains a certain substring and return true if it does and false if it doesnt.

```
regex = /^[a-z0-9]*(TEST)+'[a-z0-9]*$/;
if(myString.contains(regex)) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345194/regular-expression-matching-in-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `^` and `$` anchors, you are pretty much preventing any sub-match, because they require the entire `myString` to match the regex. So the first step is to remove those anchors. Then:

```
if (regex.test(myString)) {
```