# Regexp: How can I find form fields named with specific character sequence in a form using javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, dhtml

I have a form which among others contains text inputs that contain arithmetic data (prices)
The elements and their names are dynamically generated. I would like to only "find" fields that contain arithmetic values based on their names (i.e. an example element name would be price_500_365 (from price_PRODUCTID_ORDERID). So I want to find all text inputs containing "price" in their names or id's using regexp and sum them up. I am not sure how to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you not modify field generation at all?  Is the generation performed on the server side?

Comment: And, are you using any frameworks?  I'm assuming "no" because you have added the dhtml  tag.

Comment: Hi, 

No, its generated server side, and to make it a bit more complex fields are reloaded using ajax whenever a product or a spec changes in the order form, so the field names change as well. Thats why I needed to find all the price_* fields.

Comment: I am using jquery. Still not aware of all it's features though (such as regexp as I just found out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through the form's elements, like this:

```
var form = document.getElementById("myForm"), sum = 0;
for(var i=0; i<form.elements.length; i++) {
   var e = form.elements[i];
   if(e.type === 'text' && /price/.test(e.name)) sum += parseFloat(e.value);
}
alert(sum);
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/3sWv4/1/), if you're not dealing with `<input>` elements strictly though, you may need to change up the `if` check to include/exclude more elements.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! I was unsure of how to check against the names, trying to work with regexp. I was unaware of the test method, learned something new today :o)

Answer (score 2):

using jQuery you could do it like this:

`$('input[name*="price"]');`

Comment: Including jQuery for this is overkill I believe, since it's just a `for` loop.  *Finding* the elements is trivial, the summation isn't made any easier by jQuery IMO, or much shorter.  If the author has *other* situations improved by jQuery then by all means, but for this question, it's massive overkill.

Comment: I do have jquery included in the project indeed. A good explanation for the above suggestion is here also 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345194/regular-expression-matching-in-jquery (I just found it). 

But I was looking something like the solution below. I marked this answer as useful, but I will have to accept the one below. Thank you guys!