# strip filename from image link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable which holds a relative link for an image. This image link file name can have various lengths. For example...

```
/v/vspfiles/assets/images/d-amazingamethyst.jpg
/v/vspfiles/assets/images/cdacarbon.jpg
```

I would like to extract from this variable only the filename with out the .jpg extention and without the preceeding path. So the first example above should return d-amazingamethyst

A Jquery answer is preferred but straight javascript is ok as well. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Methods on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B5v4d/)

This returns "file-only.my"

```
var x = "/v/whatever/file-only.my.jpg";
x = x.substring(x.lastIndexOf("/")+1, x.lastIndexOf("."));
```

It is going to get the substring, starting from the index of the last `/` plus 1 (the beggining of the filename) until the last index of the `.`, cutting the extension.

You can also use the `split` function.

```
var x = "/v/whatever/file-only.my.jpg";
x = x.split("/");
x = x[x.length-1].split('.');
x.pop();
x.join(".");
```

But then you need to handle `.`s on the filename, if you cut by the index 0 it will get the wrong filename.

I use `.pop` to remove the last element on the array, which is going to be the file extension, then I join everything back with `.`s.

Comment: I used the first example an it worked and seems relatively straight forward. No need to make it more complicated than that. Thanks for your answer!!!

Comment: Deceptively simple answer, +1 (though the +1 was partially earned by just *not* using regex. I am, heartily, biased against such tools) =)

Answer (score 1):

```
var v = "/v/vspfiles/assets/images/d-amazingamethyst.jpg";

var s = v.split("/");

var filename = s[s.length-1].split('.')[0];

alert(filename);
```

first i have split the string into a array with the delimeter "/" . This gives last element as filename. Again i have split the last element as filename on the basis of "."

here is the fiddle for it. http://www.jsfiddle.net/RFgRN/

Answer (score 1):

Referencing [Regular expression field validation in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345194/regular-expression-matching-in-jquery) use a variant of Hugoware's answer.

```
var phrase = "/v/vspfiles/assets/images/d-amazingamethyst.jpg";
var reg = new RegExp("\/\S+\/",i);
phrase = phrase.replace(reg, "");
alert(phrase);
```

There are other ways rather than using a regular expression, but it's amazing how helpful regex can be.  Always a good skill to have in your arsenal. I always validate my regex's using online validation tools.  Here is one for example: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Comment: While I agree with you on the fact that reg exp solution is always helpful it tends to make be dizzy, lol, thanks for the tool as well!!