# Trouble with string matching syntax in jQuery RegEx

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to add a class to all links not containing my domain external links.

problem is some links are https, some are missing the http, some have www, etc, so i need to search for "example" in any part of the string...

here's the jQuery that i think is close:

```
.find("a:not([@href^=http://www.example.com*])")
```

here's the regex i know i want:

```
"^[^google]*$"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use lookaround, in this case negative lookahead:

```
^(?:(?!google).)+$
```

and see: [Regular expression matching in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345194/regular-expression-matching-in-jquery/345806#345806)

Answer (score 1):

found the answer...doh, should have searched better.  [Select <a> which href ends with some string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303956/jquery-select-a-which-href-contains-some-string)

```
.find('a:not([href*="google"])').not('[href^=#]').attr({ target: '_blank' });
```

*= matches anything.