# How to get variables from a string using regex in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a javascript string variable like so:

```
var somestring = "mypattern_var1_var2";
```

How can I use regex to extract var1 & var2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use the `split()` method instead if it's that straightforward:

```
var somestring = "mypattern_var1_var2";
var tokens = somestring.split("_");
var var1 = tokens[1];
var var2 = tokens[2];
```

Answer (score 2):

No need

```
var parts = somestring.split("_");
alert(parts[1] + ':' + parts[2])
```

Or get real fancy like [How can I match multiple occurrences with a regex in JavaScript similar to PHP's preg_match_all()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520611/how-can-i-match-multiple-occurrences-with-a-regex-in-javascript-similar-to-phps)

And we MUST have jQuery in the equation: [Regular expression field validation in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345194/regular-expression-matching-in-jquery/345806#345806)

Comment: Haha barely! You deserve an upvote too. It gets crazy when each answer is within seconds of each other.

Comment: @McStr - so now we should add a fiddle to demo this complex script. I wonder if we can't make it more interesting with a jQuery plugin and `each` ;)

Comment: Hahaha it's not a true javascript question if jQuery isn't mentioned. I do love me some jQuery though!

Answer (score 2):

I know you specified regex, but is there a specific reason to use it?

An alternative would be to use the `.split()` method, which would probably be easier.

```
var somestring = "mypattern_var1_var2";
var results = somestring.split("_");

var var1 = results[1];
var var2 = results[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `split()` in this situation - given that you always know that you will have a pattern in the beginning, (given that the pattern doesn't contain any '_'s)

```
var somestring = "mypattern_var1_var2";
var example = somestring.split('_');

var1 = example[1];
var2 = example[2];
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X9z6R/)