# incremental regex filterer

Tags: jquery, regex, match

I have a long list of `<a>` tags, and i'd like to filter through them live; that is, to remove the ones that don't match. I'd filter through them based on the text input in an input field. Regex would obviously search the a tag contents for a match to the input field, but i was wondering how to make it fancier, and actively filter the list like google's search bar does these days. I imagine, a key up function would trigger the regex function.

The part i don't know how to do is this:

```
[input field]ArI[/]
```

List:

```
• ArIes
• ArIstotle
```

i.e., how to make it check the nth letter of the list item.

*EDIT*

This is what i have so far, and it doesn't work.

```
$("input.CardName_Input").keyup(function() {
    var getPhrase = $(".CardName_Input").val();

    new RegExp('^' + getPhrase + '.', 'i');

    $("#Results a").each(function() {
        if (!($(this).val().match(RegExp))) {
            $(this).addClass("HIDE");
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Were you trying to bold the **`I`**? What do you mean by "a list of tags?"

Comment: @Matt Ball - list of <a> tags, my bad. The bold was supposed to represent the nth letter of the string.

Comment: Um. What about [jQuery autocomplete](http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/demo/)?

Comment: @Matt Ball - sort of what i want, not sure if it's worth extracting the key function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is what i have so far, and it doesn't work.

The code constructs a `new RegExp` but doesn't actually do anything with it. Then it passes `RegExp` (a function) to `match`. You need to assign the regexp to a variable so you can use it, and pass *that* to `match`:

```
$("input.CardName_Input").keyup(function ()
{
    var getPhrase = $(".CardName_Input").val(),
        re = new RegExp('^' + getPhrase + '.', 'i');

    $("#Results a").each(function ()
    {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.val().match(re)) $this.addClass("HIDE");
    })
});
```

**N.B.** if you don't want special characters in the `.CardName_Input` to break your code, you'll need to [escape `getPhrase`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript/2593661#2593661).

Comment: i'm not worried about special characters. I changed .val() to .text(), and then it worked perfectly. Thanks a bunch guys! And since you technically put the script together in the form i used, you'll get the check mark.

Comment: Good that you got it working. I didn't mean to poach the check mark though.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand you just have to check for the beginning of each list item string?

Then you could use something like `/^Ar./i` as expression?

In your case you could build the RegExp dynamically `new RegExp('^' + searchString + '.', 'i')`

Comment: Like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345194/regular-expression-matching-in-jquery/345806#345806 just replace the `/…/` with the `RegExp` object

Comment: @Jason: see my answer, it should be at least _closer_ to what you're trying to do.