# Error with validation process by input data

Tags: javascript, jquery

Goal:
I dont wanna retrieving any data if the input data contain any alphabet.

Problem:
If I have input data "23w" in variable ddd, the process on convertion is accceptable to be "23" in the variable currentvalue.

> I don't want it to be converted into number if the input data contain
>   any alphabet.

The sourcecode is writtin in jQuery and if possible it would be great to retreive the new solution in jQuery.

// Fullmetalboy

---

```
    var ddd = $('#field_hourInput').val();

    var currentValue = parseInt(ddd);


    // Validating message
    if(currentValue <= 0)
    {
        alert("Value must be positiv");
        nonError = false;
    }
    else if(  (isNaN(currentValue)) && (ddd != "")  )
    {
        alert("value must contain numbers");
        nonError = false;
    }
    else if(  (isNaN(currentValue)) &&  (ddd == "")  )
    {
        alert("value must contain value in the textbox");
        nonError = false;
    }
```

Comment: I love how your "Goal" begins "I don't want".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parseint() will return a number if the string begins with one, even if there is non-numbers following it. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/uQztw/

Probably better to use a regex. Something like

http://jsfiddle.net/uQztw/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to validate that. [Using regex with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345194/regular-expression-matching-in-jquery). And using regex

> [\d]

which will match any digit should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to convert string to int is Number(ddd), it does what you expect. But you could also check ddd through a regular expression, which feels better to me.

regexp-test: /^\d+$/.test(ddd)