# Jquery check if both values are starting with same text

Tags: jquery, string, variables

I jquery how to check two values starting with same texts,

My code is

```
$a = "Hello john";
$b = "Hello peter";
```

$a == $b --> False

Like this how to find variables staring string.

Comment: Have you tried anything???

Comment: i tried with like i.e, $a like $b but it's not working

Comment: `$a.split(' ')[0] === $b.split(' ')[0]`

Comment: "two values starting with" means word match or from certain number of position?

Comment: A similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345194/regular-expression-field-validation-in-jquery might give you some clues since you will want to split the string up into chunks and then compare the first one. Also you could try http://phpjs.org/functions/parse_str/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Approach 1**

### **[Click here for the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CTw6A/1/)**

```
if (!String.prototype.startsWith) {
    Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'startsWith', {
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: false,
        writable: false,
        value: function (searchString, position) {
            position = position || 0;
             return this.indexOf(searchString, position) === position;
        }
    });
}


var str = "Pankaj Garg";

alert(str.startsWith("Pankaj"));   // true
alert(str.startsWith("Garg"));     // false
alert(str.startsWith("Garg", 7));  // true
```

### **If you pay attention to the third alert, you can start the comparison after leaving some chars also**

---

### **Approach 2**

### [**Click here for the Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/evdPq/1/)

```
if (typeof String.prototype.startsWith != 'function') {
      String.prototype.startsWith = function (str){
          return this.indexOf(str) == 0;
  };
}

var data = "Hello world";
var input = 'He';
if(data.startsWith(input))
{
    alert("ok");
}
else
{
    alert("not ok");
}
```

### **Approach 3**

### **[Check here for the Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hy4DF/)**

```
var str = "Hello A";
var str1 = "Hello B";
if(str.match("^Hello") && str1.match("^Hello")) 
{
    alert('ok');
}
else
{
    alert('not ok');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check the first **word** matches, you could use:

```
if ($a.split(' ').shift() === $b.split(' ').shift()) {
  // match
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or try this http://jsfiddle.net/ApfJz/9/:

```
var a = "Hello john";
var b = "Hello peter";

alert(startsSame(a, b, 'Hello'));

function startsSame(a, b, startText){
    var indexA = a.indexOf(startText);
    return (indexA == b.indexOf(startText) && indexA >= 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $a = "Hello john";
var $b = "Hello peter";
if($a.split(" ")[0] == $b.split(" ")[0]) {
  alert('first word matched')
}
```

Note: This will compare the first word only. Not the entire string.